# What is the capacitance of this capacitor?

Tags: multimeter

On the Uni-t UT61E there is a small smd capacitor on the front of the pcb (side with lcd display) labeled C36. What is the capacitance of this component?

I do not have the component itself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP showed no prior research when clearly there is a schematic available.

Comment: I panicked and wrote this just before i found the schematic. Seems like i cannot delete this now that someone has answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, there is no easy way to go from a "C36" to a value.  "C36" simply means that it is the 36th capacitor in the multimeter.

Fortunately, there seems to be a [schematic](http://www.eserviceinfo.com/downloadsm/68103/UNI-T_UT61E.html) available. According to that, C36 is a 10uF polarised capacitor.

The same site I linked above has photos of the front and back of the board, where you can see C36 and can just make out the marking.  The top row reads 106, which also means it is 10uF. The next line looks like a 16V rating.  The small rectangular package suggests that it is tantalum.

Comment: You've earned the title "Detective", you are hereby allowed to call yourself "Detective Jack B".

Answer (score 0):

"C36" is the **label** or **name** of the capacitor **in this product**.

"C36" bears no relation whatsoever to the value. If you have the **schematic** of the product (the Uni-T UT61E) you can look up C36 and there the value will be written.

If the component is not damaged you can desolder it and use a capacitance meter to determine its value.

If C36 is damaged you're out of luck. You could reverse engineer how it is connected, sometimes that gives a clue what the value should be.